# Armazenar conteúdo de consulta em um array

Tags: php

Olá, tenho uma class que realiza uma consulta no banco de dados:

```
$itemObra->listarItensObra($_GET['id'], 0);
```

Preciso usar essa consulta varias vezes e gostaria que a consulta ocorresse apenas uma vez e que os itens fossem armazenados em um array, e posteriormente usar um `foreach` pra listar.

```
foreach ($itemObra->listarItensObra($_GET['id'], 0) as $item) {
//....
}
```

Qualquer ideia é bem vinda!

Comment: É so jogar em uma variável, `$lista = $itemObra->listarItensObra($_GET['id'], 0);`

Comment: [Se pensar na arquitetura você pode usar o singleton Pattern](https://github.com/domnikl/DesignPatternsPHP/tree/master/Creational/Singleton)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem que ver sua arquitetura mas teoricamente se o seu listarItensObra retornar o array já faz assim:

```
$resultado = $itemObra->listarItensObra($_GET['id'], 0);
```

Mas não é indicado usar parametros da forma que você está usando indico usar assim:

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$resultado = $itemObra->listarItensObra($id, 0);
```

Comment: Obrigado por responder, no caso, se eu usar uma variável ele não estará apenas armazenando a função da consulta? ao invés de armazenar o resultado na consulta? Abraço!

Comment: Ele vai armazenar o que sua função retornar. Poste o código do seu metodo listarItensObra

Answer (score 1):

Se a consulta irá ocorrer várias vezes e se os dados dessa consulta não se alteram facilmente você também pode armazenar em uma sessão.

Por exemplo:

```
$_SESSION['OBRAS'] = $itemObra->listarItensObra($id, 0);
```

Com isso você poderá utilizar em qualquer parte do seu código a $_SESSION para fazer a listagem.